# Jquery UI DateTime picker is reset to 12.00AM in onclick on textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am using a text box to take start date and binded datetime picker to it (Jquery-ui-datetimepicker-addon.js) but when iam clicking on the text box only the time is reseted to 12.00AM

Code used:

```
//Bind DateTime-Picker control
('.cdatetime-start').datetimepicker({
     ampm: true,
     hourGrid: 4,
     stepMinute: 5,
     minuteGrid: 10,
     timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
     maxDate: 0,      
});
```

Comment: Please format your question more appropriately. The bad formatting makes it quite hard to understand the code you posted.

Comment: which `datetimepicker` you are using ?

Comment: problem is resolved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is not in the datetimepicker.js,it is in my custom js which i used for getting different date time formats ,resolved it .
Thanks